# How to compress files before Rsnapshot remote backup start?

Tags: linux, backup, rsnapshot

I have some remote servers and one backup server, I'm using Rsnapshot to do the remote backup on the backup server. In my plan, I want to run shell script to compress files first, then Rsnapshot can backup the compressed files. In the Rsnapshot config file, I found `cmd_preexec`, and I want to use it, but I don't know how to write the compression script. Can anyone help me with the script?

Any help would be grateful. Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is, WHY do you want compression?

#### Compression to improve transfer speed

If you want to compress the speed of the transfer, you can add a parameter to rsync to enable on-the-fly compression during the transfer:

`rsync_short_args   -az` ([source](https://abdussamad.com/archives/361-Automating-incremental-backups-with-Rsnapshot.html))

#### Compression to reduce space requirements on backup disk

rsnapshot seems to deal rather badly with compressed backups. I found a solution to compress files on the backup server:

> (...) SOME of the files in the (2nd & beyond) archive sets can be compressed, those that aren't in a linked set.

> `find daily.1 -links 1 -size +1M ! -name "*.bz2" -print | grep -v \.svn  | xargs pbzip2 -v`

> Revert

> `find daily.1 -links 1 -name "*.bz2" -print | xargs pbzip2 -d -v`

> Only run that against the 2nd archive set (e.g hourly.1, daily.1 or weekly.1) of the shortest in your configuration.

([source](http://conshell.net/wiki/index.php/Rsnapshot#Compression.3F)).

If you want to reduce the space requirements without interference, you could also use transparent compression on the destination file system itself. I know that ZFS and BTRFS offer this natively. If your hard drive is an SSD, it might already do a transparent compression internally for all your files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i used to use rysnc_short_args -az, but I didn't see any difference. Maybe I used to test with some really small files.

Comment: There are multiple reasons why it might have no effect. Maybe the file-type was not ideal for compression? Media files (pictures, video, music) are already very compressed, so additional compression through `rsync` might have almost no effect